# Swift cocoapods with custom workspace

Tags: cocoa, swift, cocoapods

Cant seem to get this working. I want to have this File structure:

```
myApp
    - .git
    - myApp.xcworkspace
    - myApp/myApp
    - myApp/myAppTests
    - myApp/myApp.xcodeproj
    - Podfile
    - Podfile.lock
    - Pods/
    - Pods/Pods.xcodeproj
    - ...
```

This way looks a bit cleaner.

Podfile content:

```
xcodeproj 'myApp/myApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'myApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '7.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.19'
```

After I run pod install in the root dir - I get notification on Xcode that some other application modified my workspace:

- If I press Keep Current ( "pod install" modified workspace) I don't have Pods project in my workspace anymore.
- If I press Revert. I get the Pods project in my root `dir`, but when I add `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` to my `Bridging-Header.h` file - it can not resolve path to `FacebookSDK files.`

Any ideas what am I missing ? Is there somewhere in Xcode that I have to modify path to Pods project ?

Comment: Just close your xcode project before running pod install.. Xcode isn't great at handling project file changes on disk when the project still open

Comment: @ThomasKeuleers I also faced the same problem even if Xcode was not open! :( Not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: What is the exact problem ? @ThomasKeuleers